# BigQuery : How to extract year from existing datetime column and insert into the table as new specific year column?

Tags: datetime, google-bigquery

I have an actual bigquery table with a datetime column, and i want to split this datetime in other columns such as : year, month, day, quarter

I have succeeded the extract with the query :

SELECT
 date,
 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) as year,
 EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) as month,
 EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM date) as quarter
FROM
 'project.dataset.table'
;

How to get the result and update the table by creating the new year/month/quarter columns ?

I tried the method : SET year = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) WHERE TRUE

but it didn't work

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#adding_columns_to_a_tables_schema_definition)? Was something unclear?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard in fact i wish i could do my transformation with a query because i have to use it again in a SQLoperator in airflow

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the query in the scope of a DML UPDATE statement https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_statement

Comment: thanks for your help. DML syntax is the best method to resolve my problem, however the UPDATE doesn't work because i can't SET on my 'year' column since this column doesn't exist on my table schema. is there a way to use a " temporary column " ?

Comment: you can add the column to the schema via https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#manually_adding_an_empty_column and then update the contents